# what is the point of twilio's StatusCallback parameter?

Tags: twilio

The [API states](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter) that status_callback is: "A URL that Twilio will request when the call ends to notify your app."

Okay, so....does this url execute TwiML or no?

I'm really confused.

```
require 'twilio-ruby' 

account_sid = '##' 
auth_token = '##' 

@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token 

@client.account.calls.create({ 
    :from => '+18005550199', 
    :to => '+10000000000',
    :url => 'http://thisurl.com/blahblah/outbound.xml',   #plays a message to :to
    :status_callback => "http://i don't know what to do here or if this url is supposed to execute TwiML"
})
```

Comment: I would suggest you post the portion of code and explain how you would expect it to work and how it does not live up to your expectations. As it stands the question gives me no hint what you are trying to do, please do not let us google everything.

Comment: Done. I'm confused by the API doc's explanation of the parameter, so I really have no idea how to even use it. The :url parameter executes TwiML, and I'd expect :status_callback to do the same - were it not for the fact that there aren't any TwiML commands for handling the data the parameter is supposed to take care of.

Comment: Given you tagged this question with `ruby` (which I follow) you should provide some context of what you want to achieve with `twillio`, it seems to be a system to "make and receive phone calls". You should at least provide a link to the appropriate website.

Comment: I've removed "ruby" from the tags (and linked to the API), as this is primarily a twilio question. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A request to make a phone call may take a "long" time (in terms of web requests that means "several seconds"). Therefore the API cannot answer with a single return code, but it will update your status after some "some time" using a post-back URL. Try providing a URL to your own app and see what comes back.

Trouble is in order to do this you will most probably need a deployed app as you need a publicly available URL to do so (and `localhost` will *not* do :-). So you will have to setup a test domain, but most probably you will be able to use a subdomain, something like `beta.mydomain.com`in order to figure out what you will get.

Most of the examples they show on their website seem to be in PHP, but the callbacks they provide after making a call seem to expect to be called after "some time" if a connection could be established.

The API-Link you provided states rather clearly

> After a call ends, Twilio will make an asynchronous HTTP request to
>   the StatusCallback URL if you provided one in your POST. This will
>   happen regardless of the call status.

so that is what you should expect, an `asynchronous HTTP request` to the callback-link you provide. This is made asynchronously as Twillio can not maintain an http-connection for the (indefinite) duration of your call. So you should provide it with an `URL` such as

```
http://beta.mydomain.com/call-me-back-here
```

and wire it to an appropriate route (most probably a `POST`-request).

Comment: I feel dumb even asking this question, but....what URL is supposed to be used for :status_callback? The :url parameter is supposed to execute TwiML, and I have that part all set up. My confusion stems from the fact that it doesn't seem like :status_callback is supposed to do the same thing.

Comment: Using the URL you provide in `status_callback` twillio will post an HTTP request to your web app once the call is finished. There is a set of parameters specified in the API-docs that will end up in the `params` Hash (in Rails speak) and informs you about the call. In the API-docs you can find that the `:status_callback` is optional and even ignored if you provide an `ApplicationSid`. It will most definitely *not* be used to execute TwiML. P.S.: Never feel bad about asking a question.